# Проверка на пользователя в rules yii2

Tags: php, jquery, yii2, yii, rules

Как проверить что пользователь зарегистрирован и вошел по `Yii::$app->user->identity->id?`

Вот сам rules:

```
public function rules()
{
    return[
        [['comment', 'id'], 'required'],
        ['user_id', 'required', 'message' => 'Для начала зарегестрируйтесь !'],
        [['comment'], 'string', 'length' => [3,250]],

    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Проверять не в моделе а в ко́нтроллере, с помощью поведения 
https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/security-authorization